# REST API for reading from a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions

The REST API documentation doesn't have any method to read from a data extension while it has a couple of writing into it.

So is SOAP is the only API to read from a DE?

Answer (score 26):

It's not documented save for a call to `GET https://www.exacttargetapis.com/data/v1/rest`, but `GET https://www.exacttargetapis.com/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/[DE CustomerKey]/rowset/` will do exactly what you want, and it's not limited to data extensions linked to the contact model.

I've also found it will accept at least the same query string parameters as the [ContentBuilder simple asset query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetSimpleQuery.htm) plus `$top`. You can build more complex filters with `AND`, `OR`, and parentheses. `Property IS [NOT] NULL` works too.

Comment: I don't know how you found this but it is brilliant - thank you!

Comment: This is very nice solution. I just wanted to check if we can search by a particular value?Currently, this gives me all the records. In future, if records are more than 2,000 then I think it will be very time consuming.

Comment: @user36778 The route understands the same query string parameters as the [Content Builder simple asset query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetSimpleQuery.htm) route, so you could, for example, filter the results with a query string like `...rowset/?$filter=FirstName%20eq%20Robert` to get rows where FirstName is Robert. I've tested all but `like`, but that doesn't mean it's not implemented; it's finicky about which characters get url-encoded.

Comment: There are loads of undocumented api routes you can find with a call to `GET https://www.exacttargetapis.com/<module>/v1/rest`. They're poorly (not) documented, and I wouldn't rely on them for mission critical stuff, but they've proven exceptionally useful in specific situations. For instance, I once had a broken ContactBuilder relationship that was causing the web interface to hang; I resolved it by modifying the contact model with an undocumented route. Obviously, it'll give you more power than SFMC intended, so be careful with how you use it.

Comment: @ClaytonVonDras: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly.

Comment: Does anyone know if $filter still works? I've tried $pagesize and $page, all good. But when I try $filter I get "request parameter $filter could not be resolved"???

Comment: @victorcorey can you share your query parameters?

Comment: @ClaytonVonDras So this works "?$filter=subscriberkey%20eq%20f2a75707-0a03-4164-ae23-e2c0a01b12aa" but if I modify the parameters to "?$filter=emailaddress%20eq%20joe@somewhere.com" it gives me the error "request parameter $filter could not be resolved"??? emailaddress is a field in the DE.

Comment: @victorcorey I tested with one of my own data extensions and was able to reproduce your error. The solution is to quote the email address; it seems that SFMC can't handle filter values containing `.` unless they're quoted.

Also, `@` isn't url-encoded; you should make sure the filter value is encoded so you don't end up with bugs.

Comment: WORKED, thanks @ClaytonVonDras!!!:    ?$filter=emailaddress%20eq%20"joe%40somewhere.com"

Comment: Here are some examples of filters. AND and OR work even though Simple Query documentation doesn't say so. 
**using OR:** `first-name%20eq%20'John'%20or%20last-name%20eq%20'Smith'` ,  
**using LIKE:** `first-name%20like%20'Jess%'` ,  
** using IN:** `first-name%20in%20('Jesse','John')`

Comment: @ohnit nice find with that `in` operator.

Comment: Anyone figure out how to get the row number aka _customObjectKey with this? Seems to be giving me the _customObjectKey of the data extension itself.

Answer (score 2):

Probably best bet is something like https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/fetchAttributes.htm which allows you to go through DEs with are in the contact model.

For example:

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
POST /contacts/v1/attributes/search 
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
    "request": {
        "attributes": [{
                "key": "MobileConnect Demographics.First Name"
            },
            {
                "key": "MobileConnect Demographics.Last Name"
            },
            {
                "key": "Retail Orders.Order Number"
            },
            {
                "key": "Retail Orders.Order Total"
            }]

    },
    "conditionSet": {
        "operator": "And",
        "conditionSets": [],
        "conditions": [{
            "attribute": {
                "key": "Retail Orders.Order Total"
            },
            "operator": "GreaterThan",
            "value": {
                "items": ["1,000.00"]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you cite at least some of the relevant content here if the link answers the question? Links tend to break over time, so answers are much improved if they can stand on their own even were the links to go dead.

Comment: Good Point! Editing now :D

Comment: @Doug is key used in above example is external key for DE? The link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/fetchAttributes.htm seems to be not working. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Chandan, this is all based on Fully Qualified Name from Contact Builder. It doesnt required External Keys at all.