# BadRequest Error Response on DataExtension Upsert API Call

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions, marketingcloudapi

I have been looking at the [SYNC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.html) endpoints for data extensions and

I'm making calls to the endpoint: `POST /hub/v1/dataevents/key:ET_Contact_Detail/rowset`
with a body of:

```
[
    {
        "keys": {
            "Contact External Key": "10014"
        },
        "values": {
            "FirstName": "Test",
            "LastName": "User",
            "CompanyName": ""
        }
    }
]
```

which according to the configuration (I got from `contacts/v1/attributeSetDefinitions`) should be correct.

```
{
    "id": "d8b48cec-e75c-ec11-ba2e-f40343e86f58",
    "key": "ET_Contact_Detail",
    "name":
    {
        "value": "ET_Contact_Detail"
    },
    "fullyQualifiedName": "ET_Contact_Detail",
    "storageLogicalType": "DataExtension",
    "isRoot": false,
    "isSendable": true,
    "categoryID": 8515,
    "isShared": false,
    "dataRetentionProperties":
    {
        "setDefinitionID": "d8b48cec-e75c-ec11-ba2e-f40343e86f58",
        "isRowBasedRetention": false,
        "isResetRetentionPeriodOnImport": false,
        "isDeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod": false
    },
    "sendAttributeStorageName": "Contact External Key",
    "sendContactKeyStorageName": "_SubscriberKey",
    "isEvent": false,
    "relationships": [],
    "attributes": [
        {
            "id": "efb48cec-e75c-ec11-ba2e-f40343e86f58",
            "key": "Contact External Key",
            "name":
            {
                "value": "Contact External Key"
            },
            "storageName": "Contact External Key",
            "dataType": "Text",
            "isPrimaryKey": true,
            "isNullable": false,
            "isReadOnly": false,
            "displayOrder": 0,
            "ranges": [],
            "description": "",
            "length": 50,
            "scale": 0,
            "restrictedValues": [],
            "obfuscationProperties":
            {
                "valueDefinitionID": "efb48cec-e75c-ec11-ba2e-f40343e86f58",
                "storageTypeID": 1,
                "maskTypeID": 0,
                "storageType": "Plain",
                "maskType": "None"
            },
            "fullyQualifiedName": "ET_Contact_Detail.Contact External Key",
            "parentId": "d8b48cec-e75c-ec11-ba2e-f40343e86f58",
            "isSystemDefined": false,
            "isIdentityValue": false,
            "isHidden": false,
            "isUpdateable": true,
            "parentType": "Set",
            "dataSourceName": {},
            "links": {},
            "objectState": "Created"
        },
        {
            "id": "ebb48cec-e75c-ec11-ba2e-f40343e86f58",
            "key": "FirstName",
            "name":
            {
                "value": "FirstName"
            },
            "storageName": "FirstName",
            "dataType": "Text",
            "isPrimaryKey": false,
            "isNullable": true,
            "isReadOnly": false,
            "displayOrder": 2,
            "ranges": [],
            "description": "",
            "length": 250,
            "restrictedValues": [],
            "obfuscationProperties":
            {
                "valueDefinitionID": "ebb48cec-e75c-ec11-ba2e-f40343e86f58",
                "storageTypeID": 1,
                "maskTypeID": 0,
                "storageType": "Plain",
                "maskType": "None"
            },
            "fullyQualifiedName": "ET_Contact_Detail.FirstName",
            "parentId": "d8b48cec-e75c-ec11-ba2e-f40343e86f58",
            "isSystemDefined": false,
            "isIdentityValue": false,
            "isHidden": false,
            "isUpdateable": true,
            "parentType": "Set",
            "dataSourceName": {},
            "links": {},
            "objectState": "Created"
        },
        {
            "id": "dab48cec-e75c-ec11-ba2e-f40343e86f58",
            "key": "LastName",
            "name":
            {
                "value": "LastName"
            },
            "storageName": "LastName",
            "dataType": "Text",
            "isPrimaryKey": false,
            "isNullable": true,
            "isReadOnly": false,
            "displayOrder": 3,
            "ranges": [],
            "description": "",
            "length": 250,
            "restrictedValues": [],
            "obfuscationProperties":
            {
                "valueDefinitionID": "dab48cec-e75c-ec11-ba2e-f40343e86f58",
                "storageTypeID": 1,
                "maskTypeID": 0,
                "storageType": "Plain",
                "maskType": "None"
            },
            "fullyQualifiedName": "ET_Contact_Detail.LastName",
            "parentId": "d8b48cec-e75c-ec11-ba2e-f40343e86f58",
            "isSystemDefined": false,
            "isIdentityValue": false,
            "isHidden": false,
            "isUpdateable": true,
            "parentType": "Set",
            "dataSourceName": {},
            "links": {},
            "objectState": "Created"
        },
        {
            "id": "dbb48cec-e75c-ec11-ba2e-f40343e86f58",
            "key": "CompanyName",
            "name":
            {
                "value": "CompanyName"
            },
            "storageName": "CompanyName",
            "dataType": "Text",
            "isPrimaryKey": false,
            "isNullable": true,
            "isReadOnly": false,
            "displayOrder": 4,
            "ranges": [],
            "description": "",
            "length": 250,
            "restrictedValues": [],
            "obfuscationProperties":
            {
                "valueDefinitionID": "dbb48cec-e75c-ec11-ba2e-f40343e86f58",
                "storageTypeID": 1,
                "maskTypeID": 0,
                "storageType": "Plain",
                "maskType": "None"
            },
            "fullyQualifiedName": "ET_Contact_Detail.CompanyName",
            "parentId": "d8b48cec-e75c-ec11-ba2e-f40343e86f58",
            "isSystemDefined": false,
            "isIdentityValue": false,
            "isHidden": false,
            "isUpdateable": true,
            "parentType": "Set",
            "dataSourceName": {},
            "links": {},
            "objectState": "Created"
        }
    ],
    "canAddValues": true,
    "isSystemDefined": false,
    "canRemove": true,
    "canModify": true,
    "isReadOnly": false,
    "links": {},
    "objectState": "Created"
}
```

But when i make any call to the endpoint I get

```
{
    "message": "Primary key 'Contact External Key' does not exist.",
    "errorcode": 10000,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

I have checked in the Data Extensions portion of Marketing Cloud and I do see a row in the UI with the value of `10014`.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: is "Contact External Key" the name of the PK field?

Comment: At least from what I can make from the Configuration it is. In the `attributes` node of the configuration its the only one with `IsPrimaryKey` of true.

Comment: Where are you getting the configuration from?

Comment: Im getting them from the `contacts/v1/attributeSetDefinitions` endpoint

Answer (score 0):

The typical issue on other similar questions with this was a missing "key:" in the URL preceding the customer Key, but you have that.

Can you try using the "fullyQualifiedName" of the PK field from the response?

Meaning

```
 "keys": {
            ET_Contact_Detail.Contact External Key": "10014"
        },
```

This is a suspicion because all these REST methods for Data Extensions should work similarly. And in this other example, this time reading from a DE using REST: [REST API for reading from a Data Extension](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110296/rest-api-for-reading-from-a-data-extension) (check answer by Doug), this pattern of referencing the DE was used accordingly. "MobileConnect Demographics" and "Retail Orders" being the DE keys there.

Speculatively, this "prefixing" being needed might also have to do with the field name "Contact External Key" containing spaces, and interestingly in the linked example, all of the fields do.

In contrast, in some other examples on this site, the key fields did not, but seemed to work without a prefix. (e.g. [REST API error: Primary key '(primarykey)' does not exists](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280090/rest-api-error-primary-key-primarykey-does-not-exists))

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that the issue is that this data extension is a shared data extension which can only be accessed via the parent level context in API. Either this or it is a synchronized data extension, which cannot be written to.

If it is a shared data extension, then try using a token at the parent/enterprise level of your account to do this DE upsert call and see if that works.

If it is synchronized, you will need to make the changes in your source data and then it will be pushed down to Marketing Cloud in the sync DE.

The error `"Primary Key 'xyz' does not exist."` displays even if you enter in an invalid value for the key. This is a poor error handling experience, as it is misleading - but as I do not believe this is the case for the ID, must be caused due to the 'key:' prepend.